# How to use Join on linked servers

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get results of a customer from two linked servers remotely. i need to sum the points of every cust_id but am having problems with my query

```
SELECT  sum(cust_point) as total
FROM [192.168.23.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] where cust_id='0100015388' 
INNER JOIN [192.168.13.4].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch]
ON cust_id.[192.168.23.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch]=cust_id.[192.168.13.4].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can always use a `UNION ALL` here if you like.. this will allow you select other fields as well if you include a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT  SUM(cust_point) AS total
FROM    (
            SELECT  cust_point
            FROM    [192.168.23.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch]
            WHERE   cust_id = '0100015388'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT  cust_point
            FROM    [192.168.13.4].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch]
            WHERE   cust_id = '0100015388'
        ) t
```

Comment: thanks it works very well. one more help.!! is there any way you can write this code into a procedure so that a user can input different cust_id dynamically and get results. thanks a gain for your help

Comment: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/162/how-to-create-a-sql-server-stored-procedure-with-parameters/  you just need a parameter for cust_id and replace the hard coded `0100015388` with the parameter name

Answer (score 1):

I think you have your query syntax a little scrambled there. Try this.

```
SELECT sum(cust_point) as total 
FROM [192.168.23.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] A
INNER JOIN [192.168.13.4].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] B ON A.cust_id=B.cust_id
WHERE cust_id='0100015388'
```

Comment: I was in the process of typing the same... but I think column `cust_point` can be found in both table so it will give an error. Same for the WHERE clause, `cust_id` can be found in both tables.

Answer (score 1):

As you want the sum of cust_point of both of the table. Please find the query below

```
Select( (SELECT  sum(cust_point)
        FROM [192.168.23.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] where cust_id='0100015388') +  
    (SELECT  sum(cust_point)
        FROM [192.168.13.4].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] where cust_id='0100015388') ) as total
```

Comment: actually your solutions works but my problem is the sum of points are not matching my actual points. form example if i run an indivital sum of points in single statements a get diferent values as below

Comment: select  sum(cust_point)as total_points from loyal_summery_branch where cust_id='0100015388'
SELECT sum(cust_point) as total FROM [192.168.10.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] where cust_id='0100015388'

Comment: cust_point is in both the table and you are looking for sum on both the tables for a particular A.cust_id?

Comment: @Emma provide schema of both tables.

Comment: yes am looking for the sum of the particular cust_id, can u help with my code please

Comment: select  sum(cust_point)as total_points from loyal_summery_branch where cust_id='0100015388'
SELECT sum(cust_point) as total FROM [192.168.10.9].[POSDBV4].[dbo].[loyal_summery_branch] where cust_id='0100015388'

Comment: with those two queries, the first on gives a total of 100points and the second one a total of 20points. my problem is to get the sum of these points in one single query. any help please